# What is being said in this short audio? (Attempt provided)

Tags: translation

[Here](https://instaud.io/38Pl) is the link. The translation I have here with me is this:

Humans in the living world, and the souls in the Afterlife, they must be wise to a limit, and react only to the given situation, but if you keep asking about the truth...

Transcription should be this (no clue if this is or isn't correct, made with Google speech API)

이승 사는 인간들이나 저승 사는 귀신들이 다 필요한만큼 현명하고 추워 집만큼 반응 하면 되는데 말이지
자꾸 진실이 뭐냐고 물어봄

I can't understand what does "they must be wise to a limit, and react only to the given situation" mean and I suspect that it is a case of bad translation. Thanks for any help.

Comment: “이승 사는 인간들이나, 저승 사는 귀신들이나, 필요한 만큼 현명하고, 주어진 만큼 반응하면 되는데 말이지. 자꾸 진실이 뭐냐고 물어봄― (안 되지.)”

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) 이승 사는 인간들이나 저승 사는 귀신들이나 필요한만큼 현명하고 주워진
만큼 반응 하면 되는데 말이지 자꾸 진실이 뭐냐고 물어보면 (안되지)

Humans in the living world, and the souls in the world of the dead
are sufficient when they are wise as much as they need and they
react only to the given situation, but if you keep asking about the
truth, (then it is not correct).

2) 이승 사는 인간들이나 저승 사는 귀신들이나

Humans in the living world, and the souls in the world of the
dead

필요한만큼 현명하고 주워진 만큼 반응 하면

when they are wise as much as they need and they react only to the
given situation

되는데 말이지 are sufficient

자꾸 진실이 뭐냐고 물어보면 (안되지)

but if you keep asking about the truth, (then it is
not correct).

3) Interpretation : If you are in high position, then you need a lot of
wisdom. If not, then you need small. With this, we are enough. And
we apply same logic to reaction : React as much as the size of
problem-situation.

That is, we are fine if we rule out "excessive and insufficient",
which is everybody's knowing. But if you repeat asking, then you
walk into a bad state.